# xcodeが予期しない理由で終了

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

xcode6.3.2
下記不具合が発生しています。対処方法分かる方見えましたらお教え下さい。
手順）
ioSアプリを作成
provisioning profile作成
itunes connectのアプリ登録も問題なく完了
最終手順でvaildateまでは成功します。
最期のsubmit to App Storeのボタンを押すとしばらくすると
xcodeが強制終了してしまい「xcodeが予期しない理由で終了」と
でます。
osxのアップデートはきちんとしています。
先月作ったアプリは問題なく公開までできました。
xcodeをアップデートしたことぐらいしか先月との違いがありません。

Comment: XcodeのOrganizer以外のウインドウをすべて閉じて、Organizerのウインドウだけが開いている状態でやってみてください。